# Excluding view cluster maintenance from transport

Tags: view, abap, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary

I want to exclude a view cluster maintenance from being transported (standard SAP customizing view cluster `FISKVC_TAXSECTN`)

To do this, I copied the maintenance views of that view cluster and excluded the new maintenance views from the transport system. (my own maintenance views consist of standard sap customizing tables)

Then I created a new own view cluster on top of my own maintenance views in the hope that I have more control what it does. It is still not possible to maintain the cluster without transporting.

Transaction `SOBJ` for my own Viewcluster (type C) says Transport -> Automatic transport.
My problem: this field is not changeable. I can change some other fields but not this one.
What prevents this field from being changed? How can I change it to no transport?

**Edit**

I looked in the source code of transaction `SOBJ`: there is hard code to exclude view clusters from being able the maintain the field transport.

```
* Set input off for object transport for viewcluster objects
IF v_obj_h-objecttype EQ gc_cluster_type.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-name EQ 'V_OBJ_H-OBJTRANSP'.
      screen-input = gc_off.
      MODIFY SCREEN.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

So the question is: where can I maintain the transport property of a view cluster if it is not possible to be maintained in transaction `SOBJ`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood it right. You want to suppress the "select transport" dialog when you save your new cluster view?

Comment: Yes. To be able to maintain the customizing tables in quality and production system.

Comment: Just a guess but try to suppress transports for all the customizing tables (or defined maintenance views if you are preferring that way) that are in the cluster view. I think that when at least one of them has recording selected in the table maintenance generator you will not be able to change the transport field for the cluster view. Try to go to the table maintenance generator for each of those tables and change the recording routine to "no, or user, recording routine". Then check if the transport field for cluster view is editable.

Comment: I already excluded transportation in the maintenance generator for the two maintenance views as you described before I posed this question (and checked again now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to edit the values in the production environment, set the flag ["ongoing settings"](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/d2/b73c885b8a11d395da00a0c930dcc1/content.htm) ("laufende Einstellung") in the transport object definition (transaction `SOBJ`). This will not prevent you from transporting stuff from the dev environment, but it will allow for local changes in the production system without transports at the same time. Use with caution.

(This is a perfect example why stating the actual business requirements is always a good idea...)

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you to save the views and cluster into [local transport request](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4a368c163b08418890a406d413933ba7/7.4.20/en-US/193f5bf8a4b011d285090000e8a57770.html)?

[image]

Local TRs are not transportable to anywhere. I tried it with your `FISKVC_TAXSECTN` and it works fine.

Comment: This would mean writing into a local transport in production environment.

Comment: no. Current/ongoing settings work [only within production](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Current+Settings) and if you want make different settings in this cluster between DEV/QA, local TR is the only option

Comment: In this case a local TR was not necessary. But I can't look it up why, I have no access to the system where we did it at the moment.